# Set font-size to value from an input field. (value from jquery .val())

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set different `font-size` to the values received from `$("#company").val()` and `$("#firstname").val()` in `#page2`. have tried with `css()` and stylesheet but I can't seem to get it right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#printid").hide();

  $("#print").click(function() {
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#printid").show();
    $("#page2").html($("#company").val() + "<br />" + $("#firstname").val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label for="company">Comp: </label>
      <input id="company" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" type="text">
    </p>
  </form>
  <input type="button" id="print" value="Skriv Ut" />
</div>

<div id="printid">
  <p id="page2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Copied parts of the code, missed </form> and the last ) in html(). But it I want to have different font-size on 'company' and 'firstname' in page2?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to wrap each value in its own `span` with different classes, then use CSS to style them, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#printid").hide();

  $("#print").click(function() {
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#printid").show();
    $("#page2").html('<span class="company">' + $("#company").val() + '</span><br /><span class="name">' + $("#name").val() + '</span>');
  });
});
```

```css
.company { font-size: 1.5em; }
.name { font-size: 0.8em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label for="company">Comp: </label>
      <input id="company" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" type="text">
    </p>
  </form>
  <input type="button" id="print" value="Skriv Ut" />
</div>

<div id="printid">
  <p id="page2"></p>
</div>
```

Also note that the input had an id of `name` yet you were using `firstname`, but I presume that was just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `css` adding a class to them ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#printid").hide();

  $("#print").click(function() {
    $(".form").hide();
    $("#printid").show();
    $("#page2").html($("#company").val() + "<br />" + $("#name").val())
  });
});
```

```css
#page2{
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label for="company">Comp: </label>
      <input id="company" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" type="text">
    </p>
  </form>
  <input type="button" id="print" value="Skriv Ut" />
</div>

<div id="printid">
  <p id="page2"></p>
</div>
```